# Airplay Apple Music from iPhone or Homepod to Macbook

Tags: macos, ios, airplay, apple-music, homepod

When I start the music on a iPhone or Homepod via Siri, how do I move the already playing music to my MacBook? Can I only airplay music from the MacBook to HomePod but not vice versa? How do I airplay music from iphone to macbook?

Comment: Not sure for Apple Music, but if you're using Spotify you can select within the Spotify iOS app to choose which device you are playing the music from. However you need to have Spotify open on the MacBook for it to recognise you have Spotify open on the Mac.

Comment: True, but also here I cannot select it from the Mac. I wanted to switch to apple Music because of the homepods but Spotify UX is like 1000x better -.-